# Where do I edit the Django password_reset_recover.html file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am trying to style IDP pages for my site. I've set up the base.html, and styled login.html and join.html. I'm having trouble finding the password_reset_recover html file though.

In the base I link to `{% url 'password_reset_recover' %}` and it takes me to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/passwordsrecover/` URL.

The problem is that the recover URL is giving me the the same exact content that is on the `login.html` screen, which is not what I want.

I'm looking to find where the `password_reset_recover.html` file is so that I can edit the html directly.

```
<div id="buttons"><!--Buttons-->

<div id="loginCta">
  <div class="simpleBtn">
    <a href="{% url 'password_reset_recover' %}"><input type="button" value="Forgot Password?"/></a>
  </div>

<div class="mainBlueBtn">
    <a href="{% url 'core:login' %}"><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></a>
</div>

<div class="simpleBlueBtn">
    <a href="{% url 'core:register' %}"><input type="button" value="Sign Up"/></a>
</div>

</div>
```

My current folder setup:

[image: My current folder setup]

Edited to include the urls.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from django.conf.urls import url

from core.views import Register, Activate

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', 'core.views.profile', name='profile'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'core.views.login_view', name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'core.views.logout_view', name='logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', Register.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^accounts/activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$', Activate.as_view(), name='activate'),
```

]

Comment: The problem is not the HTML, it is the URL. The wrong pattern is capturing that request.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still learning all of this. Do you mind going into a bit more detail? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what your urls.py looks like?

Comment: You need to show the URL for that includes "password_reset_recover", which that doesn't.